# Is there a constant for max/min int/double value in dart?

Tags: dart

Is there a constant in dart that tells us what is the max/min int/double value ?

Something like `double.infinity` but instead `double.maxValue` ?

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/23392

Comment: Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41717

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For `double` there are

`double.maxFinite` (`1.7976931348623157e+308`)
`double.minPositive` (`5e-324`)

In Dart 1 there was no such number for `int`. The size of integers was limited only by available memory

In Dart 2 `int` is limited to 64 bit in native code, but it doesn't look like there are constants yet. If ever.
The values are:

```dart
const int maxInteger =  0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
const int minInteger = -0x8000000000000000;
```

For dart2js different rules apply

> When compiling to JavaScript, integers are therefore restricted to 53 significant bits because all JavaScript numbers are double-precision floating point values.

The maximal finite web integer is therefore also `double.maxFinite`, and the maximal web integer is `double.infinity`. Minimum values are just the negative of those.

The maximal *precise* integer would be 2^54 (the first integer that cannot be represented as a double is that plus one).

```dart
const int maxPreciseWebInt = 0x20000000000000;
```

Comment: I was just about to answer my own question with this statement. Thanks haha !

Comment: I use `1<<63`, which isn't very readable, but it's concise and a comment is enough to explain it

Comment: Note that `1 << 63` isn't portable since it isn't appropriate for the web, where Dart does not use 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 17):

here you are the int64 max value:

```
const int intMaxValue = 9223372036854775807;
```

for dart web is 2^53-1:

```
const int intMaxValue = 9007199254740991;
```

"The reasoning behind that number is that JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point format numbers as specified in IEEE 754 and can only safely represent integers between -(2^53 - 1) and 2^53 - 1." see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: I believe OP is asking if there is a predefined constant (like the ones e.g. C provides).

Comment: Note that this isn't an appropriate maximum value for the web, where Dart does not use 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 16):

I found this from [dart_numerics](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_numerics) package.

[image]

Comment: This is quite good, but doesn't have the equivalent for Double

Answer (score 15):

### Max int value in dart:

```
const int maxValue = -1 >>> 1;

print(maxValue);
```

### Output :

```
9223372036854775807
```

### Logic:

-1 is represented internally in binary format : `11111111 11111111 11111111 ... 11111111`

`>>>` is bitwise shift right zero fill operator.

bitwise shift right zero fill operator will shift the bits towards right side and fill zeros from the left size.

**Syntax of `>>>`**

```
number >>> times_to_shift;
```

So in this expression `-1 >>> 1` `-1` is *number* and **1** is *times_to_shift hence* `>>>` operator will shift the binary value of `-1` towards right side **one** time. After the operation the result value will be :

`01111111 11111111 11111111 ... 11111111`

Notice the bits are shifted towards right side and zero is filled from the left side and this is the **maximum integer value**.

Comment: This answer is a maths muscle flex. Never thought I would use this operator in Dart in my life.

Comment: Does not work on the web. See earlier answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50429767/717964

Comment: @DanSyrstad what do you mean by that it doesn't work for the web can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Udesh The numeric representation of integers in Dart generated javascript (web) is limited to 2^54 - 1 rather than 2^64 - 1, so you can get a different result on the web vs. native code (see the link in my comment). See also https://dart.dev/guides/language/numbers#bitwise-operations which describes this in detail. Maybe once Dart compiles to WASM we won't have to deal with these differences.

Answer (score 11):

#### No,

Dart does not have a built-in constant for the max value of an `int`

#### but this is how to get the max value

Because `int`s are signed in Dart, they have a range (inclusive) of [-2^31, 2^31-1] if 32-bit and [-2^63, 2^63 - 1] if 64-bit. The first bit in an `int` is called the 'sign-bit'. If the sign-bit is 1, the `int` is negative; if 0, the `int` is non-negative. In the max `int`, all the bits are 1 except the sign bit, which is 0. We can most easily achieve this by writing the `int` in hexadecimal notation (integers preceded with '0x' are hexadecimal):

```
int max = 0x7fffffff; // 32-bit
int max = 0x7fffffffffffffff; // 64-bit
```

In hexadecimal (a.k.a. hex), each hex digit specifies a group of 4 bits, since there are 16 hex digits (0-f), there are 2 bit digits (0-1), and 2^4 = 16. There is a compile error if more bits than the bitness are specified; if fewer bits than the bitness were specified, then the hexadecimal integer will be padded with 0's until the number of bits is the bitness. So, to indicate that all the bits are 1 except for the sign-bit, we will need to use `bitness / 4` hex characters (e.g. 16 for 64-bit architecture). The first hex character will represent the binary integer '0111' (7), which is `0x7`, and all the other hex characters will represent the binary integer '1111' (15), or `0xf`.

Alternatively, you could use bit-shifting, which I will not explain, but feel free to Google it.

```
int bitness = ... // presumably 64
int max = (((1 << (bitness - 2)) - 1) << 1) + 1;
```

Comment: But how can you detect if 32/64 bit at runtime?  Or compile time would do at a pinch

Answer (score 3):

Use `double.maxFinite()` to convert `int`

```dart
const maxValue = double.maxFinite.toInt();
const minValue = -double.maxFinite.toInt();
```

Comment: While debugging for web, I tried to pass this to a `InputDecoration`'s `hintMaxLines` but it silently fails. It I input the value directly, it complains about Javascript's smaller `int` size. However, `-1 >>> 1`, as per the other answer, returns `2^31 - 1`, which is just fine.

Comment: In Android, though, `-1 >>> 1` still returns `2^63 - 1`, which still causes `hintMaxLines` to silently fail...

Answer (score 0):

There are constants available in package `package:fixnum/fixnum.dart` depends on whether you need `Int32` or `Int64`.

#### Int64

```
Int64.MIN_VALUE.toInt();
Int64.MAX_VALUE.toInt();
```

https://pub.dev/documentation/fixnum/latest/fixnum/Int64/MAX_VALUE-constant.html
https://pub.dev/documentation/fixnum/latest/fixnum/Int64/MIN_VALUE-constant.html

#### Int32

```
Int32.MIN_VALUE.toInt();
Int32.MAX_VALUE.toInt();
```

https://pub.dev/documentation/fixnum/latest/fixnum/Int32/MAX_VALUE-constant.html
https://pub.dev/documentation/fixnum/latest/fixnum/Int32/MIN_VALUE-constant.html