# Is there the equivalent of INT_MAX in dart?

Tags: dart, integer, constants

The question is in the title: is there a constant INT_MAX (the maximum value of an integer) in the Dart language?

I don't care what it is, I just want to use it as an initialization constant to, for example, find a minimum value in a List.

I note that there is a `double.maxFinite` which I could use as in

`int i = double.maxFinite.toInt();`

but that somehow seems wrong to me.  Or is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429660/is-there-a-constant-for-max-min-int-double-value-in-dart

Answer (score 1):

There is no maximal integer value across Dart platforms.

On native platforms, the maximal value is 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (2<sup>63</sup>-1). There is no constant provided for it.

On web platforms, the maximal integer value is `double.maxFinite`.

If I had to do something which needed an initial maximal value (finding the minimal element of a list, perhaps), I'd prefer to start out with the first element, and throw on an empty input.

As a second choice, I'd use `num` for the accumulator and use `double.infinity` as starting value. Then I'd check at the end and do something useful if the value is still infinite.

Comment: Understood. Using the first element, which I have done, somehow has always felt a bit kludgy to me, but I suppose no worse than assigning INT_MAX. I just thought perhaps I'd missed something in my reading of the documentation. Intuitively, at least to me, it seems as if there should be manifest constants just as there are in many other languages. Oh well.

Comment: It would be convenient if there were such a constant, but people tend to disagree on whether they want `2^53` (aka "max precise integer double"), `double.maxPositive` or `double.infinitt` as the maximal integer value on the web. All of these are `int`s (if you check with `is int` - they are equal to `.floor()` of themselves, so they are considered integers.)

Comment: If you use `theIterable.reduce((a, b) { ... })`, on the first iteration you're looking at two elements of the list, and return the new candidate.  No need for a MIN or MAX value for that.